# Одинаковые имена пользователей

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано

Обнаружил двух разных пользователей с одинаковыми именами

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240201/konstantin

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240203/konstantin

Я правильно понимаю, что такого быть не должно?

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что не должно, но почему-то это так (видимо разрабы в какой-то момент решили `это не баг, а фича...`, а теперь поезд уже ушел)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На StackOverflow, что на русском, что на английском, имена не уникальны.

Например, на [странице со списком пользователей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users) одних лишь Алексеев 13 страниц:

[image: Лёха-Лёха, чего ж тебя так много?]

Это не баг, это фича.

---

А вот одинаковые аватарки скорее всего означают один и тот же email, и следовательно, одного и того же человека.

Comment: странно, имхо, только сумбур вносит, ну да ладно

Comment: А именно 435 штук.

Comment: @AnotherOther: Много как-то.

Comment: 9*4*12+3, так как-то.

Answer (score 4):

Техническую сторону хорошо объясняют два соседних ответа.

На практике такое сочетание:

- две или более учётных записи с почти одинаковыми ID,
- часто с одинаковыми именами,
- участвующие в одном вопросе,

почти всегда указывает на то, что это один и тот же человек, который задал вопрос без регистрации, а потом закрыл браузер. Потом он пытается дополнить ответ или ответить на комментарии — но сайт не позволяет — поэтому он пишет «ответы».

Comment: Это, вероятно, означает, что незарегистрированного юзера, задающего вопрос, имеет смысл предупредить о том, что он не сможет комментировать, если закроет браузер.

Comment: Но закрытие браузера не стирает куки.

Comment: @Qwertiy значит что-то другое происходит, нужно разобраться.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, это вполне возможно, уникальным является `ID`.
Имя же сменить можно в настройках: "**Править**" -> "**Редактировать Профиль**" -> "**Отображаемое имя**".